# How to write a string to a cmd prompt using ProcessBuilder in Java?

Tags: java

I have a batch (.bat) program that asks that user to supply a hostname and password. (Two fields) I am using a separate Java application to gather to automate this task and so I need it to enter multiple hostnames at once into the script. However, I am having a hard time accomplishing this goal using ProcessBuilder.
Please take a look at the below code:

This code I have only redirects the input and output to the java process. However, I would solely like to write to the cmd. Please let me know if there is any way. Thanks

```java
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd" ," /k d: && cd DATA\\Virtualization Scripts\\EMC ESXi Grab && Script_Run");
        //inherit IO
        pb.inheritIO();
        Process process = pb.start();
        process.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Grab hostname and password using scanner and pass hostname and password as command line to the script. All can be achieved making small tweak in the above program. It is also necessary to modify the bash script also to accept hostname and password as commandline.

Comment: @Sambit Scanenr won't work in this case because I want the java application to automate the task of having a user repeatedly type in there response.

Comment: You have mentioned "that asks that user to supply a hostname and password.", how will you grab these two fields for the bash script to execute ?

Comment: @Sambit First off, I made a mistake I meant to say "Batch Script". Also, I have a GUI setup and so the long term goal is for the user to supply the hostname and password for multiple servers, and have the java application run off each, one at a time.

Comment: It still creates confusion. Can you tell us your actual requirement so that we can help you.

Comment: @Sambit Sure, so I am creating a Java GUI that prompts users to enter one or multiple host names in which they will be passed to a secondary script to grab log files for those selected hosts. The issue I am having is having my Java application write to the script. The first part of the script prompts ```Enter Hostname:``` and then it prompts for ```Enter password:```. After that it runs a task and then should go to the next host. Hopefully the explanation helped a bit.

Comment: It means your batch script asks for HostName and password to run ? is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @Sambit Correct!

Comment: If you post your batch/bash script, I will help you

Comment: @Sambit It was written by Dell. One second

Comment: @ Sambit ```@ECHO OFF
set /p host= Enter hostname:
set /p password= Enter password:
"D:\UPSDATA\Virtualization Scripts\EMC ESXi Grab\EMC-ESXi-GRAB-1.3.10\emcgrab.exe" -host %host% -vmsupport -user root -password %password% -case 00000000 -legal -customer UPS -party 00000 -contact user -phone NA -email NA 
exit```

Comment: Give me sometime, I will provide you solution.

Comment: @Sambit Thanks a million, in the meantime I will also work on it.

Comment: I have given the answer, hope it is useful to you.

Comment: @Sambit I will do some editing and testing, but it looks promising. I will let you know by the end of the day if it works. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can try, it will definitely work, hope it is useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

@Tharriott, as per our discussion, first of all you have to modify a bit your batch script like this. I provide below the code.

```
@ECHO OFF 
set host=%1 
set password=%2

echo Host Name : %host%
echo Password : %password%

"D:\UPSDATA\Virtualization Scripts\EMC ESXi Grab\EMC-ESXi-GRAB-1.3.10\emcgrab.exe" -host %host% -vmsupport -user root -password %password% -case 00000000 -legal -customer UPS -party 00000 -contact user -phone NA -email NA 

exit
```

Imagine that the name of the batch script is **emc-grab.bat**.

Now you have to run the above batch file like this.

> :/emc-grab.bat

one example is like this

> D:/test/emc-grab.bat abcd.dellemc.com pa$$word99

**Now what is next ?**

In your java gui program, capture hostname and password, then in the processbuilder class, pass the complete command along with the file name, hostname and password.

I provide below the code snippet.

```
String hostNameAndPassword = "captured Host Name"+" "+"captured password";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd" ,"some path:/emc-grab.bat "+hostNameAndPassword);
```

Try it, it will solve your problem.

Comment: I get an error with the password though when I run your code. The password is short but it keeps passing a password much longer than the one I entered. ```Command line options: -host servername.example.com -vmsupport -user root -password ***************************************************************************************************```

Comment: This is the code: ```String hostName = "servername.example.com"; String password = "password1234"; ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd"," /k d: && cd DATA\\Virtualization Scripts\\EMC ESXi Grab\\EMC-ESXi-GRAB-1.3.10 && ESXRun.bat " + hostName + " " + password ); pb.inheritIO(); Process process = pb.start();```

Comment: Before executing java program, simply run the batch by passing hostname, password as command line and see how they are getting printed and get executed. If that is successful, then you can implement in Java. Always break the problem into small pieces so that it is easier to resolve.

Comment: Yes, I continue to get the same error when I execute via cmd. I will try to see if I can resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you it worked correctly, the batch script you gave me is good.

Comment: By the way, we have already developed this kind of grab utility, you can find a lot in Emc.